# error en wampserver , como solucionar este error

Tags: php, wampserver

[image: Por qué recibo este error de wampserver ?]

estoy recibiendo este error de wampserver , como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Si copias y pegas ese texto en inglés en [google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=es&op=translate) lo entenderás y podrás actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.